# Matlab calculation with laplace analysis is different from what I got in LTspice

Tags: matlab, laplace-transform

Here is the circuit diagram.

[image]

Waveform for the current passing through voltage source.
[image]

The code I use for Matlab .

```
syms L R C R s Rp t

R1 = 1/(s*C);
R2 = s*L + R + 1/(s*C);
Rp = R1 * R2 / (R1 + R2) % parallel Resistance

f(t) = ilaplace(5/s/Rp,t) % main current

f1(t) = subs(f, {L, R, C}, {10^(-6), 22, 3.3*10^(-9)}) % replace L,C,R with real world values

fig1 = figure('Name','Oscillator','NumberTitle','off');
t = 0:10^(-9):10^(-6);
p1 = plot(t,f1(t), '-o', 'MarkerSize',8,'color',[0.7 0.2 0.7], 'DisplayName', "Circuit of Oscillator")
p1.MarkerFaceColor = [1 0.5 0];
p1.LineWidth = 2
xlabel({'time','(in s)'})
xticks(0:10^(-7):1/1000)
ylabel({'Current','(in A)'})
```

The diagram I got from Matlab.
[image]

Why is it different even though I choose *"Skip Initial Operating Point Solution"*

---

update with label on nodes.

[image]

My waveform look like this.

[image]

Circuit Analysis in s-domain.
$$
R_1(s) = sL + \frac{1} {sC} + R
$$

$$
R_2(s) = \frac{1} {sC}
$$

$$
R_p(s) = \frac{R_1 R_2} {R_1 + R_2}
=
\frac{1+C\,R\,s+C\,L\,s^2}{C\,s\,\left(2+C\,R\,s+C\,L\,s^2\right)}
$$

$$
I(s) = \frac{5} {s} \frac{1} {R_p}
=
\frac{5\,C\,\left(2+C\,R\,s+C\,L\,s^2\right)}{1+C\,R\,s+C\,L\,s^2}
$$

With the help of Matlab for the inverse Laplace transform.

$$
I(t)
=
5\,C\,\delta \left(t\right)+\frac{10\,\sqrt{C}\,\sin\left(\frac{t\,\sqrt{4\,L-C\,R^2}}{2\,\sqrt{C}\,L}\right)\,{\mathrm{e}}^{-\frac{R\,t}{2\,L}}}{\sqrt{4\,L-C\,R^2}}
$$

Comment: Are you sure that you have plotted the input current in Matlab? It looks like you have plotted the L1 - C2 - R2 branch current.  Try to plot L1 current in LTspice.

Comment: @G36 I have updated the question and try to add some laplace analysis.

Comment: Plot L1 current. Because I_in current must be very large thanks to C1 capacitor. At transient C1 will short the voltage source.

Comment: @G36 yes, but I think my matlab is the plot for main current.  Could you please check my laplace analysis in the updated question?

Comment: Your inverse Laplace transform is correct.  But the problem is with C1 and Dirac delta. The infinity charging current at t = 0 does not exist in the real world. And this is what LTpscie is trying to tell you (C1 shorts-out voltage source at t = 0).  Do you see the problem?

Comment: @G36 Great Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, let's first check your Laplace calculation:

$$\text{I}_\text{in}\left(t\right):=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}\left[\underbrace{\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_{\space\text{i}}}{\text{s}}}_\text{input voltage}\cdot\left(\underbrace{\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\space\text{||}\space\left(\text{R}+\text{sL}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\right)}_\text{input impedance}\right)^{-1}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag1$$

Where \$\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\$.

Comment: Using the inverse Laplace transform, we find:

$$\text{I}_\text{in}\left(t\right)=\hat{\text{u}}_{\space\text{i}}\text{C}_1\left(\delta\left(t\right)+\frac{2\sqrt{\Delta}}{\text{C}_1}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{\text{R}t}{2\text{L}}\right)\sinh\left(\frac{t}{2\text{L}\sqrt{\Delta}}\right)\right)\tag2$$

Where \$\Delta:=\frac{\text{C}_2}{\text{C}_2\text{R}^2-4\text{L}}\$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SPICE, while using quasi-ideal elements to try to *approximate* real-life counterparts, doesn't do well with ideal cases. What you are looking for is an ideal case and, if you look at your result (I haven't checked it), you have a \$\delta(t)\$ in there.

Therefore, Matlab is cheating on you by not showing you the Dirac impulse, keeping only the relevant rest of the answer.

LTspice, OTOH, is showing you exact response of what you have modelled: a stepped 5 V source (due to the `uic` flag) driving that complex impedance. And, if you zoom in -- either by <kbd>LClick-Drag</kbd> or by <kbd>RClick</kbd> on the Y axis then select `0.18` for top, `-0.02` for bottom, and `0.02` for the tick, you'll see this, which is the same result as in Matlab, only more complet, due to the presence of the Dirac:

[image: same result in LTspice, only more complet]

So, you had the answer all along, you just didn't dig up enough for it. ;-)

Comment: It doesn't look like LTSpice. What software did you use for this?

Comment: @kile It is LTspice. Do not forget that you can change the color scheme in LTspice.

Comment: @kile [It's LTspice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAKYh.png). It is customized, yes but, it probably also confuses you because it's in Wine, not Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you must mimic the way a step is input to your network. If you do skip startup, then ltspice will just plot the settled waveform and skip initial transients.

If you want to test the step response of your network, then you need an step input signal. This is done by using the "pulse" type of input.

You can set it in this way:
[image]

You can also see that you have an startup behavior at the very beginning of your waveform, but the correct way to test the step response is to use a pulsed signal like in the picture.

Comment: I tried to use your setup. But it's quite off from what I got from Matlab.
https://i.imgur.com/nXp8EJM.png

Comment: @kile can you please name your nodes? What kind of input did you use in Matlab? If it's a very ideal input step, you could try 1p rise time, maybe

Comment: @kile: since we've "fixed" the startup issue with using LTSpice, please _edit your question_ to describe what you're doing _now_.  And name your nodes, so we know what we're looking at in the plots.

Comment: There's also a checkbox somewhere -- I think in the simulation dialog -- to start with all the sources set to zero, which will do the same thing -- at least in this instance.

Comment: @ErnestoG What nodes do you mean?

Comment: @kile input and output

Comment: @TimWescott I am trying to compare the main currents (Passing through voltage source) between matlab and LTspice

Comment: @ErnestoG The input is the voltage source and the output is the current going through voltage source

Comment: @kile if you label your nodes, then your plots are more readable. Currently I see V(n001). I have no idea which node n001 is...

Comment: Yes, we understand what you're trying to do.  A circuit node is any point where two or more components come together -- we are asking you to please _edit your schematic_ in LTSpice to give the relevant ones names, then re-run your simulation, then _edit your question_ with the new graph.  If we can't see _how_ it is different from your Matlab simulation, we can't tell you what may be wrong.

Comment: @ErnestoG I have updated the question accorrding to your suggestions. I hope you can understand what I am measuring now.

Comment: I think you have try finer transient steps in your ltspice simulator. And did you try using smaller rise/fall times?

Comment: @kile the inverted current response you see is just due to the way ltspice plots entering or leaving currents. Normally, if the current is going out of a node, the current has a negative sign. Ltspice doesn't allow you to plot currents by port, so they're probably plotting the top port of the vsource.

Comment: @ErnestoG what is top port here? You mean `L1 - C2 - R2` branch current?

Comment: @kile I meant that the vsource has 2 ports, though I think a better name is terminal. One of them is connected to ground, while the top is connected to your circuit. The current plotted is the current through that top terminal of your vsource, and since it's current "coming out" of that terminal, it has a minus sign.

Comment: @ErnestoG This is not correct: the `uic` flag not only makes the source act as a stepped source but, all the circuit will start from zero initial conditions, calculating any and all transients. The reason OP's pic shows what it shows is because LTspice gives the full, correct answer, and the Dirac in there obscures the response OP is looking for.